# Setting Environment variable for Aspectj

Tags: java, aspectj

How to set environment variable for aspectj. when ajc is run in command prompt it showing like this

C:\Users\UAS1>ajc
java does not exist as C:\Program Files\Java\jre6;C:\aspectj1.6\lib;\bin\java
please fix the JAVA_HOME environment variable
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

How to resolve this..

Thanks  in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have some extraneous stuff in your `JAVA_HOME`. It should contain just one directory, probably `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6`.

The extra stuff should probably have been put in another variable instead, like `CLASSPATH` for example. Check your other environment variables and make sure they are OK.